# sklearn.model_selection: GridSearchCV vs. KFold

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

[Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) is the explain of **cv** parameter in the  **sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV**:

> cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
>
> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs for cv are:
>
> - integer, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified)KFold

For example, can I replace

```
CV = 5
```

to

```
CV = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
```

or replace in the opposite way. CV is called in the function

```
GridSearchCV(estimator=XXX, ... , cv = CV)
```

I am not sure whether any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can replace the `cv=5` with `cv=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)`. Leaving it set to an integer, like 5, is the equivalent of setting it to either `KFold(n_splits=5)` or `StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)`, depending on the model you pass to the `estimator` parameter of `GridSearchCV()`